# How to calculate the increase in temperature due to drop?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, gravity, energy, temperature

Question- Calculate the rise in temperature in celcius in a bucket of water after it is dropped from 50 m where acceleration due to gravity is 10.

I know that I need to find the amount of energy absorbed and then find out the increase in temperature using the specific heat of water but cant do it as the mass isn't mentioned. This is a question in the book of my coaching center. I am a seventh grader. Thanks.

Comment: Show your effort please. This is not a homework help site.

Comment: The mass will appear identically on both sides of an appropriate equation.

Comment: I have given at least 2 hours worth of time to solve this. The problen is not the question itself but how to get the amount of energy which the water at the top has since the mass isnt mentioned

Comment: +Rob could you throw in a hint?

Comment: Homework based questions are never really helped with. This isnt really a homework question... I just saw a question which looked challenging and attempted it.. with no result

Comment: Assume a mass and perform your calculations.  As Rob hinted, your final answer will not depend on the mass you assume.

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya - The idea (i guess) is that the kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ the bucket has on moment of impact is completely converted to heat $Q=mc_p\Delta T$ and absorbed by the water. Which of these variables don't you know? can you calculate it based on the given info?

Comment: By the way, it's not the drop that will increase the temperature... it's the sudden stop at the end.

Comment: @nluigi I dont know the mass ... plz help

Comment: If I dont depend on the mass and just assume 1 then according to formula-  v^2 = u^2 + 2as  and then we get v= underoot of 1000 which doesnt make sense to me!

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya - Do you know understand why it doesn't depend on mass?

Comment: @nluigi I guess its because the mass cancels out at the end

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya - exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I hate answering my own question but here goes-

V^2 = u^2 + 2as
=> V^2 = 1000

Assuming mass 1kg,

Kinetic energy = 1/2 × mass × velocity^2
=> 500 joules => 1200 cal

Hence increase in temp = 0.12 ○ Celcius